# Structured Binding in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dictionary

Is there something similar to C++'s [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) in C#?
I would like to use it in a `foreach` loop.
C++ example:

```cpp
for (const auto& [key, value] : myMap) {
}
```

Comment: [Deconstruction?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct) `foreach (var (key, value) in myDictionary)`. KeyValuePair got a Deconstruct method in .NET Standard 2.1.

Comment: @canton7 Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @canton7 but there is a slight difference. The `&` in C++ means, that this is some kind of reference, but in C# it's definitely not a reference. But in most cases this doesn't matter.